# ArcGIS Online won't connect from ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online

I've installed ArcMap 10.3 and want to use Arcgis online from the desktop. At the beginning it was not possible to connect to Arcgis online. The menu was "grey" , so not available. ESRI support gave us some url to reference in our proxy and now we can access to Arcgis online menu. When I launch Arcgis Online, I've got a windows with an error "an erro occurred, check your internet connection" . The problem is that nobody can help us to find the issu. Esri support in France say that it is a problem with our computing infrastructure....

I used a tool "Fiddler Web" to see what happen when we launch Arcgis Online and I see the following url : www.arcgis.com:443

The port 443 is open in our proxy.

---

In Fiddler these lines appear when I connect to Arcgis online :

[image]

... but i don't know how to interpret it. Actually, it is the first time I use it!

Comment: In Fiddler do you see a response from the call to arcgis.com? Especially the HTTP Status Code and any response description. 

I'm assuming the help from ESRI was to configure your proxy server in ArcCatalog - we had a lot of issues where our proxy server to connect to the web required authentication and ArcGIS wasn't providing credentials (the proxy returned the error HTTP 407 - Proxy authentication required) . In the end we opened the firewall to permit direct connections to ArcGIS Online by passing the proxy.